# How to fix mysql error with inserting data

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to input data into a mysql database, however I keep running into an error (1064).

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| meas_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| sensor_id   | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| svalue      | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| units       | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dt_measured | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lat         | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| long        | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have tried insert statements such as:

```
INSERT INTO measurements (sensor_id,svalue,units,dt_measured,lat,long) 
VALUES (223344,22.3344,DEG,2019-07-09T15:46:53-07:00,533244.3,60446.0);
```

I thought that this insert statement would work but I keep encountering an error.

Comment: Please tell us what the error is

Comment: You probably want to use [`decimal`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) instead of float for your non-integer numeric columns

Comment: `(223344,22.3344,'DEG','2019-07-09T15:46:53-07:00',533244.3,60446.0)` use single quotes

Comment: The error im now getting is ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long) 
VALUES (223344, 22.3344, 'DEG', '2019-07-09T15:46:53-07:00', 533244.3, 60' at line 2

Comment: Please add the error message to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote string literals: `'DEG`'

And datetime literals: `'2019-07-09 15:46:53'`

Also MySQL doesn't accept ISO 8601 format for datetimes. It only accepts `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.

See documentation:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Comment: Firstly thank you!, secondly i'm still encountering an error. ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long) VALUES (223344, 22.3344, 'DEG', '2019-04-03 15:46:53', 533244.3, 60446.0)' at line 1

Comment: long is a reserved word. Use a different column name or enclose it in backticks. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-L

Comment: `long` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). You can use it if you put inside back-ticks.